# GluonCV, action recognition tutorial error

Tags: python-3.x, mxnet, gluon

I've been trying to run the [GluonCV tutorial for action recognition](https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/build/examples_action_recognition/demo_ucf101.html).

I didn't modify anything, but I'm getting an error at the very beginning of the script, when applying the transformation function to the image.
The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

To try and solve it, I wanted to replace the list with a single image, so I tried:

```
img = transform_fn(img.asnumpy())
plt.imshow(np.transpose(img, (1,2,0)))
plt.show()
```

but in this case, I get another error:

```
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

Any idea on how to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had to update gluoncv to a later version.
A little weird, because I installed it following the instruction on the tutorial page, but it works after the update.